# Insert Range into Email Body

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that will take a range of cells and output them into an email, between some text.

I can't work out how to insert the range. I'm not sure whether the issue is that my range isn't declared correctly, or I'm not calling it correctly.

Currently I have:

```
Sub Email()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Body As String
Dim Rng As Range

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set Rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A7", Range("A7").End(xlDown))

Body = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Some text, followed by numbers:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        Rng & vbNewLine & _
        "More text"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .Body = Body
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You're going to have to send it as an attachment unless you can concatenate the data into a string.

Ron deBruin has a great piece of code for this. You'll need to adapt it to add your text.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail4.htm

Comment: Please note this isn't a good [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Noted. Thank you.